# How to set up pipeline in Azure Devops for robot framework?

Tags: azure-devops, automated-tests, azure-pipelines, robotframework, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have automated testcases in robot framework and I want to run it in Azure Devops. I followed a solution online where I have created a pipeline using the following yaml . There are multiple folders in the source Azure repo that I am using and my testcases is one of them. I need help to locate my testcase folder path
Please let me know what I can add to the yaml file for the same

[image: The yaml file that I am using right now and its not able to locate the testcase file which is Onboarding.robot]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move the same command lines for robot test you run on your local machine or other CI/CD services to Azure Pipelines to run using the [PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) or other available script tasks.

For your case, you can try the command line below:

```
robot path/to/example.robot
```

The **`path/to/example.robot`** can be either relative path or absolute path of the robot file which defines the automated testcases. This command will execute all tests in the specified robot file.